# generate multiple sql scripts dynamically in oracle

Tags: unix, plsql, oracle12c

I want to generate multiple insert sql files dynamically at some location like /home/work .The select query has some transformation also in date fields.

```
create table orders (order_id number , order_name varchar2(10) , ord_dt date);
create table ar_orders (order_id number , order_name varchar2(10) , ord_dt date);

create table sales (sales_id number , prod_cd varchar2(10) , sales_dt date);
create table ar_sales (sales_id number , prod_cd varchar2(10) , sales_dt date);
```

Expected sql files :

1. ar_orders_insert.sql

   ```
    prompt TRUNCATE AR_ORDERS TABLE
    truncate table AR_ORDERS;
    prompt insert INTO AR_ORDERS
    insert /*+ append */ into AR_ORDERS
    (order_id,
     order_name,
     ord_dt
     )
    select a.order_id,
           b.order_name ,
           coalesce(to_date(b.ord_dt,'YYYYMM'), a.ord_dt)
    from orders a,
         ref_tab b
    where b.order_id = a.order_id;
    commit;

    insert /*+ append */ into AR_ORDERS
    (order_id,
     order_name,
     ord_dt
     )
     select a.order_id,
            a.order_name ,
            a.ord_dt
    from orders a,
         AR_ORDERS b
    where b.order_id = a.order_id;
   ```

   commit;
2. ar_sales_insert.sql : similar insert sql like above.

   ```
   prompt TRUNCATE ar_sales TABLE
        truncate table ar_sales;
        prompt INSERT INTO ar_sales
        insert into ar_sales
        (sales_id,
         prod_cd,
         sales_dt
         )
        select a.sales_id,
               b.prod_cd ,
               coalesce(to_date(b.sales_dt,'YYYYMM'), a.sales_dt)
        from sales a,
             ref_tab b
        where b.sales_id = a.sales_id;
        commit;





   insert /*+ append */ into ar_sales
    (sales_id,
     prod_cd,
     sales_dt
     )
     select a.sales_id,
            a.prod_cd ,
            a.sales_dt
    from sales a,
         ar_sales b
    where b.sales_id = a.sales_id;

    commit;
   ```

I am trying this but looks like i am going in a wrong direction. There are many tables for which i need to generate the sql files. I have create only two tables for demonstration.

```
    SET SERVEROUTPUT ON ;
DECLARE
 v_select_qry  varchar2(32767);
 v_insert_qry  varchar2(32767);
 v_ar_tab      varchar2(50) := 'REF_TAB b';
 v_from_str     varchar2(2000);
 v_where_str    varchar2(3000);
 v_str        varchar2(2000);
 
BEGIN
  
FOR i IN ( 
SELECT OWNER,TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME  LIKE 'AR_ORD%')
loop

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PROMPT: TRUNCATE AR_ORDERS TABLE');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PROMPT: INSERT INTO AR_ORDERS');
  
   v_str := 'truncate table ' || i.TABLE_NAME;
   v_from_str := 'FROM '||i.TABLE_NAME ||' a,'||chr(10)|| v_ar_tab;
   v_where_str := 'WHERE b.order_id = a.order_id; ';
    
 FOR K in (select column_name from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS where table_name = i.table_name and OWNER = i.OWNER order by column_id)
  loop

     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(k.column_name);
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_from_str);
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_where_str);
 
   END LOOP;
END LOOP;

END ;
/
```

Comment: You haven't said what problem you are having?

Comment: i am not getting the expected result out of this logic ..